# Terraform 0.9.6 remote config outdated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I have been trying to update some of the terraform scripts from version 0.6.13 to 0.9.6. In my scripts I had before

```
     terraform remote config -backend=s3 \
      -backend-config="bucket=my_bucker" \
      -backend-config="access_key=my_access_key" \
      -backend-config="secret_key=my_secret" \
      -backend-config="region=my_region" \
      -backend-config="key=my_state_key"
```

and then

```
     terraform/terraform remote pull
```

Which was pulling the remote state from aws. Upon running `terraform apply` it will give me the exact resources that needed to be updated/ created based on the remote tfstate that is stored in an s3 bucket.

Now the issue I'm facing is that `remote pull` and `remote config` commands are outdated and don't work anymore.

I tried to follow the instructions on https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/remote.html
    however it was not much helpful.

From what I understand I would have to do an `init` first with a partial configuration which presumably would automatically pull the remote state as following:

```
`terraform init -var-file="terraform.tfvars"\
 -backend=true \
 -backend-config="bucket=my_bucker" \
  -backend-config="access_key=my_access_key" \
  -backend-config="secret_key=my_secret" \
  -backend-config="region=my_region" \
  -backend-config="key=my_state_key"`
```

However it doesn't really pull the remote state as it was doing before.

Would anyone be able to guide me into the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `terraform remote pull` any more. Terraform by default will automatically based on the [`refresh` flag](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/plan.html#refresh-true) which defaults to true.

Comment: As a complete aside, I'd be very worried about making such a large version jump but also to one that is now 2 years old. Do you have a plan for migration on to a more recent version of Terraform?

Comment: yes, however all our systems are using 0.9.6 version atm. The plan is to update the scripts to this version first then do a migration for all to the newer version

Comment: So according to your answer, the `init` command should do both `remote config` and `remote pull` right?

Comment: No, it doesn't pull. `init` just sets up how the backend is being used etc, running the `plan`/`apply`/etc commands with `-refresh=true` will handle pulling state.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I had to add a minimal backend configuration such as

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
  }
}
```

in my `main.tf` file for it to work